# A not_so_familiar exception in Apache Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I encountered the following when I tried to do a spark submit:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Is this a known problem?

Thanks and regards,

The following program is able to reproduce the above error message:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

class anomaly_model(val inputfile: String, val clusterNum: Int, val maxIterations: Int, val epsilon: Double, val scenarioNum: Int, val outputfile: String){
   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Anomaly Model")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   val data = sc.textFile(inputfile)

def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val inputfile = "sqlexpt.txt"
    val clusterNum = 5 
    val maxIterations = 1000 
    val epsilon = 0.001
    val scenarioNum = 10
    val outputfile = "output.csv"
    val am = new anomaly_model(inputfile, clusterNum, maxIterations, epsilon, scenarioNum, outputfile)

  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information, preferably with a minimal example that shows the problem. It's pretty much impossible to guess just from a stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Probably it was my mistake to define the main method inside the class... I should have defined it inside a companion object instead (I come from a Java background!).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put main class in anomaly_model class, you may need to change "class" to "object". And yes, if you want to have anomaly_model a class, you may need to put main method in another object.

In anomaly_model class:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

class anomaly_model(val inputfile: String, val clusterNum: Int, val maxIterations: Int, val epsilon: Double, val scenarioNum: Int, val outputfile: String){
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Anomaly Model")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val data = sc.textFile(inputfile)
}
```

And in Main.scala:

```
import anomaly_model

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit{
        val inputfile = "sqlexpt.txt"
        val clusterNum = 5 
        val maxIterations = 1000 
        val epsilon = 0.001
        val scenarioNum = 10
        val outputfile = "output.csv"
        val am = new anomaly_model(inputfile, clusterNum, maxIterations, epsilon, scenarioNum, outputfile)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a null value in one of your variables, as the message says.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and had made the same mistake as you. `anomaly_model` should be an `object` and not a `class`